# Who is in The Flash's prison?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

In *The Flash* TV series the basement of Star Labs is used as an off-the-books black site prison. No trial, no appeals, no windows, just a bare cell with transparent door.

Who is in the this prison? Current and former inmates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, only Bloodwork, albeit temporarily.

Originally, metahumans were a rare and extraordinary occurrence for which the world had no capability to contain or understand.  Therefore, the trampling of civil rights in the name of necessity as Team Flash unlawfully detained powered beings in the so-called "Pipeline."  This was the butt of many jokes by the fans and the show runners, who make nods to the violations, deprivations, and sustainability of the pretense.

By Season 2, metahumans had been sufficiently integrated across the "Arrow-verse" that A.R.G.U.S., under Lyla Michaels- the wife of John Diggle- takes on the responsibility of containing and rehabilitating metahumans (like King Shark).  As an off-books covert-op quasi-illegal shadowy organization, it had the power to disappear and hold metahumans without issue.  So the Pipeline falls into disuse for anything but short stints of holding or containment until A.R.G.U.S. can take custody.

By Season 5, metahumans are so prevalent in the world by various means that many more metahuman countermeasures become mainstream (such as power dampeners) and thus Iron Heights Penitentiary finally has the capability to incarcerate powered persons.  By this point, law enforcement have restraints that can take powers or stop a metahuman, so Team Flash is completely out of the prisoner game.

One of the best ways to illustrate this change in circumstances is to compare the amount of metahumans with manifest powers on Team Flash.  At the start, the one and only powered being was its namesake: The Flash.  However, presently, there are no less than 6 ACTIVE members with supernatural metahuman powers... not to mention retired, reserved, allies, and non-powered but super-science characters that may-as-well have powers.

Bloodwork is a present exception as he can't be held in the Pipeline, but for technobabble reasons can be contained by the Mental Augmentation Chamber (MAC), where he presently resides, but is likely to be transferred to A.R.G.U.S. off-screen.

---

List of former detainees:

```
Julian Albert/Alchemy (released)
Barry Allen/The Flash (released)
Oliver Queen/The Flash (escaped; alternate reality only)
Shawna Baez/Peek-a-Boo (escaped during relocation; was later incarcerated in Iron Heights; was eventually released)
Roy Bivolo/Rainbow Raider (escaped during relocation)
Dinah Drake/Black Canary (released)
Wade Eiling/Goldfinger (released)
Mark Mardon/Weather Wizard (escaped during relocation; currently incarcerated in Iron Heights)
Cynthia/Gypsy (released)
Henry Hewitt/Tokamak (released)
Curtis Holt/Mr. Terrific (released)
Laurel Lance/Black Siren (escaped with Prometheus' aid)
Kyle Nimbus/The Mist (escaped during relocation)
Kara Danvers/Supergirl (released; alternate reality only)
John Diggle (alternate reality only)
Linda Park/Dr. Light (escaped)
Cisco Ramon/Vibe (released)
Rene Ramirez/Wild Dog (released)
Hartley Rathaway/Pied Piper (escaped; released in current timeline)
Mitch Romero (escaped; deceased)
Mick Rory/Heat Wave (released)
Nora West-Allen/XS (released; later erased from existence)
Caitlin Snow/Killer Frost (released)
Music Meister (escaped)
Eobard Thawne/Reverse-Flash (released)
    Eobard Thawne's time remnant (released to return to his own time) 
Harrison Wells (released)
Wally West (released; briefly held here to protect him from Alchemy)
Hunter Zolomon/The Flash/Zoom (released; later deceased) 
Philip Master/Acid Master
Abra Kadabra (released to be taken to Earth-19 to be executed; presumably deceased)
Farooq Gibran/Blackout (killed prior to being stored in the pipeline as a corpse)
Hannibal Bates/Everyman (released based on a deal with Eobard Thawne; killed in the process of fulfilling his end)
Jake Simmons/Deathbolt (killed by Leonard Snart during relocation)
Janet Petty/Null (powers absorbed by Clifford DeVoe, leaving her dead)
Russell Glosson/The Turtle (killed by Harry Wells to obtain a sample of his brain tissue to learn how to use his powers to slow a speedster down)
Tommy Merlyn/Prometheus (committed suicide by cyanide capsule)
Tony Woodward/Girder (released and set loose as a distraction; killed in the process)
```